# Controlling Push notification

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-silverlight

I want to control push notifications (toast) coming from WNS server before it displays on screen..I can do it in Android but can I do it in Windows Phone..??

Comment: what type of action you are intending to do?

Comment: Before toast appears on the screen I want to compare its parameter to some value & if it satisfies the condition then I want to show the notification....Here is the string I am sending through push notification........<toast launch=\"#/abc.xaml?var=12345><visual><binding template=\"ToastText02\"><text id=\"1\">" + subject + "</text><text id=\"2\">" + body + "</text></binding></visual></toast>

Answer (score 1):

you can use toast notifications in your case. Toast notifications are handled by OS. you can get payload in launch argument at OnLaunched Event of App.

[Client sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WNS-Notifications-for-950d473b)

[Server app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WNS-for-Windows-and-83fd21f6), you can use it for testing. You can also use emulator for push testing.

Comment: The code inside OnLaunched Event will run after app is launched..But before that notification appears on the screen...I don't want that..I want to catch data before notification appears and decide to show it or not.....

Comment: Then in this case use raw notification. Add background task and in Run add your logic and show own toast there.

Comment: Accept answer if it helped you.. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a raw notification, this is a notification that your phone handles while the application is running.

When you create your pushchannel you can use the OnPushNotificationRecieved Event to do logic when reciving a notification.

This way your logic will trigger before the notification appears on the screen **IF** the application **is running**.

If the application is **not** **running** it will be a regular Toast.

Example:

```
    _channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
    _channel.PushNotificationReceived += OnPushNotificationReceived;

   private void OnPushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.NotificationType)
        {
            case PushNotificationType.Badge:
                this.OnBadgeNotificationReceived(args.BadgeNotification.Content.GetXml());
                break;

            case PushNotificationType.Tile:
                this.OnTileNotificationReceived(args.TileNotification.Content.GetXml());
                break;

            case PushNotificationType.Toast:
                this.OnToastNotificationReceived(args.ToastNotification.Content.GetXml());
                break;

            case PushNotificationType.Raw:
                this.OnRawNotificationReceived(args.RawNotification.Content);
                break;
        }

        args.Cancel = true;
    }

    private void OnBadgeNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
    {
        // Code when a badge notification is received when app is running
    }

    private void OnTileNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
    {
        // Code when a tile notification is received when app is running
    }

    private void OnToastNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
    {
        // Code when a toast notification is received when app is running

        // Show a toast notification programatically

        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(notificationContent);
        var toastNotification = new ToastNotification(xmlDocument);

        //toastNotification.SuppressPopup = true;
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastNotification);
    }

    private void OnRawNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
    {
        // Code when a raw notification is received when app is running
    }
```

Comment: I have question where your answer would fir quite well to I think, I will test it later. I only have one additional question compared to your solution. But you could look at my question and get some points :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460872/depending-on-page-viewed-act-on-toast-notification-wp8-1-silverlight-receiving