# Getting the current page when receiving a toast notification (WP8.1 Silverlight, receiving WNS toast notification)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, dispatcher

I have an event that fires when the app is live and I receive an notification `CurrentChannel_PushNotificationReceived`. In this function I want to find out which page is currently displayed to know if the notification should update content on the page. The question is therefore twofold, how to know which page is currently displayed and interact with the toast notification.

**Update**
The issue is that I cannot interact with the elements because of clash with the OS threading (Dispatcher).

Therefore using the below code it allows me to access the content of the message. But I am still not able to get the info of the current_page

```
  _channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
_channel.PushNotificationReceived += OnPushNotificationReceived;
```

private void OnPushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.NotificationType)
        {
            case PushNotificationType.Badge:
                this.OnBadgeNotificationReceived(args.BadgeNotification.Content.GetXml());
                break;

```
        case PushNotificationType.Tile:
            this.OnTileNotificationReceived(args.TileNotification.Content.GetXml());
            break;

        case PushNotificationType.Toast:
            this.OnToastNotificationReceived(args.ToastNotification.Content.GetXml());
            break;

        case PushNotificationType.Raw:
            this.OnRawNotificationReceived(args.RawNotification.Content);
            break;
    }

    args.Cancel = true;
}

private void OnBadgeNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
{
    // Code when a badge notification is received when app is running
}

private void OnTileNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
{
    // Code when a tile notification is received when app is running
}

private void OnToastNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
{
    // Code when a toast notification is received when app is running

    // Show a toast notification programatically

    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(notificationContent);
    var toastNotification = new ToastNotification(xmlDocument);

    //toastNotification.SuppressPopup = true;
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastNotification);
}

private void OnRawNotificationReceived(string notificationContent)
{
    // Code when a raw notification is received when app is running
}
```

**Question**

How do I access the current page information in the different `onXXXXNotificationReceived`. The current snippets work but not within these functions:

```
var currentPage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;
        var tempBool = currentPage.GetType() is BC_Menu.StartUp.SecondScreen;
```

or

```
RootFrame.CurrentSource;
```

My guess is it is because of the UI-thread. So how can I use the dispatcher to get the information? I have tried some solutions with the dispatcher, but I cannot await the information, and therefore it is not applicable.

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation op = App.RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<Uri>(() =>  
            {
                return RootFrame.CurrentSource;
            })
        );
        await op; //Not awaitable.
```

Comment: Where you defined the CurrentChannel_PushNotificationReceived method ?

Comment: In app.xaml.cs file for the project. The event is bound on the first page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to await the dispatcher to the UI thread. Simply dispatch to the UI thread and then perform the rest of your logic, like displaying the toast or navigating to a page, from within the UI thread...

Register the event...

```cs
var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
channel.PushNotificationReceived += Channel_PushNotificationReceived;
```

On the event handler, cancel displaying the notification and then dispatch to UI thread...

```cs
private void Channel_PushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    // Make sure you cancel displaying the toast on this thread (not on UI thread)
    // since cancellation needs to be set before this thread/method returns
    args.Cancel = true;

    // Then dispatch to the UI thread
    App.RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
    {
        var currPage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;

        switch (args.NotificationType)
        {
            case PushNotificationType.Toast:
                // TODO
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Do all of your code inside the dispatcher's delegate. All your code will be executing on the UI thread... you'll be able to navigate pages, obtain current page, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Try this. Create a static property on App.xaml.cs.

```
public static object CurrentPageInfo { get; set; }
```

And assign the page type or page name to the property on 'OnNavigatedTo' method on every page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
  var currentPage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;
  App.CurrentPageInfo = currentPage.GetType() is BC_Menu.StartUp.SecondScreen;
}
```

So that you can identify the page source type on receiving notifications by accessing the `App.CurrentPageInfo` property. Hope it helps!

Comment: While that is a solution, it is not really a nice one. I had hoped not introducing statics, and being able to query the info directly in the functions. But maybe it is the only way (?) :/

Comment: You just need to get the page source type & it is not working on the push event. So  just gave you the alternative solution. What will be the issue with using static properties? Hope you will get some nice solution.soon  :)

Comment: I will probably start a bounty just to clarify if another solution is possible. And if no one else can find another solution, then hey more points for you :) Appreciate your well meaning thoughts ! (Hoping too)

Comment: yeah! that will be great :)